# Angular2 typescript - kendo ui grid column template (click) not working

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I am new to Angular and do not understand why the ng-if and (click) events are not working from kendo grid column template.

I want a button which needs to be conditionally visible and on click I need to navigate to other page in spa. With command I couldn't dynamically handle the visibility based on cell value. So, chose template, but with template click event is not working.

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { TWCGridComponent, PanelComponent } from 'infrastructure.export';
import { IssueDTO } from 'issue.webmodel.export';

import { IssueBusinessService } from '../../webBL/issue.business.service';

declare var $: any, moment: any;

@Component({
selector: 'twc-issue-list',

templateUrl:                   'webApp/issueDetail/Shared/sections/issueList/issue.list.template.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TWCGridComponent, PanelComponent],
viewProviders: [],
styles: [`
  :host { display: block; }
`]
})

export class IssueListComponent {
dataSource: Array<IssueDTO> = [];
gridOptions: kendo.ui.GridOptions;
child: JQuery;
// private $el: JQuery;
@Output() knownIssuesCount: ReplaySubject<{}> = new ReplaySubject(1);
@Input() set searchParams(params: any) {
    if (params) {
        this.initSearch(params);
    }
}
constructor(private issueBusinessService: IssueBusinessService,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.gridOptions = {
        sortable: false,
        scrollable: false,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "id", title: "Issue ID / Status / Summary", width: "40%",
                template: `
                  <div class="cellLine">#:id# \/ <span class='status #:statusName.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')#'>#:statusName.toUpperCase()#</span></div>
                  <div class="cellLine">#:title#</div>`
            },
            {
                field: "category", title: "Category / Type", width: "30%",
                template: `
                  <div class="cellLine">#:primaryIssueCategoryName#</div>
                  <div class="cellLine">#:primaryIssueCategoryTypeName#</div>
                `
            },
            {
                field: "updateTime", title: "Created / Updated", width: "20%",
                template: this.gridFormatters.lastUpdate
            },
            {
                field: "command", hidden: false,                   
                template: `<div><button type="button" onclick="toggleOrder()" class='btn btn-rounded #:readAllowed# icon-twc-08'</button></div>`                   
    };
    /* tslint:disable */
    function toggleOrder() {
        alert("hey");
    }
    /* tslint:enable */     
}
toggleOrder() {
    alert("hey");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (click)="onClick()" and I don't see a *ngIf in your code.  The "()" around the event name tells angular2 its an event.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer but the (click) event is not hitting the method toggleOrder() which is inside the component . i tried                       <div *ngif="0==1"><button type="button" (click)="toggleOrder()" class='btn btn-rounded #:readAllowed# icon-twc-08'</button></div> .    Both ngif and (click) events are not working. but when i write onclick = "alert(hello)" it does work , so i want to know why the html onclcik works but not the angular(click) event is recognizeed from column template of kendo grid.